# How to manipulate a Python object to get information on time

Tags: python

I have this type of data

```
0 days 11:07:00.000000000
```

I would like to keep only `0 days 11:07`. The format is `dtype('O') -  (Python) objects`. How can I do?

Comment: `dtype('O') -  (Python) objects` is not specific enough to be useful.  You need to figure out what the structure of these objects is and how to get at the data.  Python has facilities like `dir()` for examining objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean this

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'c': ["0 days 11:07:00.000000000"]})
df['c'].dtype
```

Output

```
dtype('O')
```

Then you can use this

```
df['c'].astype(str).apply(lambda x : ":".join(x.split(":")[0:2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is string you can use [rpartition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition)

```
def convert(data):
    return str(s.rpartition(':')[0])
```

Example:

```
>>> s = '0 days 11:07:00.000000000'
>>> s = str(s.rpartition(':')[0])
>>> s
0 days 11:07
```